# Find a word in the .dat files and copy

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

Let's say my folder is: "C:\sample\" . There are two types of .dat files.

One is

`Head #Index
    Name= "DbResultDataHeadStruct"
    TypeNo
      VarType = REG_DWORD 0x8
      Data = ""
    TypeA
      VarType = REG_DWORD 0x8
      Data = ""`

Other one is:

`Head #Index
    Name= "DbResultDataHeadStruct"
    TypeNo
      VarType = REG_DWORD 0x8
      Data = ""
    TypeB
      VarType = REG_DWORD 0x8
      Data = ""`

As you see only differences is TypeA and TypeB. I want to copy/cut file if there is TypeA in the .dat file to "C:\sample\TypeA" and same for TypeB to "C:\sample\TypeB". This batch file will always wait for new file.
I found this code below but I couldn't fix it according to me. Maybe it'd be helpful.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "PATTERN=*.dat"
set "SOURCE=C:\sample\"
set "TARGET=C:\sample\TypeA"
set "STRING1=TypeA"
set "STRING2=TypeB"

pushd "%SOURCE%" && (
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('findstr /S /M /I /R /C:"\<%STRING1%\>" "%PATTERN%"') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%E in ('findstr /M /I /R /C:"\<%STRING2%\>" "%%F"') do (
        ECHO copy "%%E" "%TARGET%\%%~nxE"
    )
)
popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with findstr and move commands.

I have added timeout too. It's checking folder in every 10 seconds.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "source=C:\sample\*.dat"
set "target=C:\sample\TypeA\OpMode"
set "target2=C:\sample\TypeB\Error"
set "searchString=OpMode"
set "searchString2=Error"

:loop
set "found="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    findstr /m /i /l /c:"%searchString%" "%source%" 2^>nul 
') do (
    if not defined found set "found=1"
    move "%%a" "%target%"
)



set "found="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    findstr /m /i /l /c:"%searchString2%" "%source%" 2^>nul 
') do (
    if not defined found set "found=1"
    move "%%a" "%target2%"
)

timeout /T 10

goto loop
```